# how to run a python file in interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I have never used python and I am trying to run session_eval_main.py file that processes 3 text files and outputs the result. but when I try to run it in the interpreter I get the following error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'session_eval_main' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me here.

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to be using `python session_eval_main.py` in a command prompt or similar... It looks like you're trying to type the name of the script into `IDLE` or some other editor...

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
python session_eval_main.py
```

I'm assuming that you are referring to this [script](https://code.google.com/p/session-eval/source/browse/trunk/session_eval_main.py?r=3).  If this assumption is true, then you can add flags:

```
Usage:
$ python session_eval_main.py 
--qrel_file=qrels 
--mapping_file=topics_sessions 
--run_file=runs
--dup_file=dups 
--per_session=0 
--cutoff=10 
--write_to_file=0
```

If you need help with what each flag does, run this:

```
$ python session_eval_main.py --help
```

Comment: make sure you open python and not IDLE. IDLE is a document editor. you want to open the python command line. To use the code jh314 posted above, simply open command prompt and enter that in.

Comment: Also, make sure that `session_eval_main.py` is in your current directory when you run it.